# Excel automatically pasts across worksheets when I paste a row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on Excel 2019 file with multiple worksheets on Windows 10

when I copy a row and paste it in one sheet it automatically pasts the same row on the rest of worksheets without me wanting to do so.

I tried to fresh install office and this only happens on one of the PCs at my work.

and it doesn't always happens
I'm going crazy, any ideas how to solve or debug this.

it's been ruining my files silently and I need to find a solution.

any tip would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is "Across Worksheets" checked in Home pane, Editing section, Fill drop-down list? It requires more than one sheet to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Excel in safe mode running the following command:
Press Win + R, type "excel /safe" in the blank box, press Enter. If it works fine in safe mode, please check the add-ins in your excel and disable them.

Click File > Excel Options > Add-Ins on the left side of the dialog. Then click the drop-down arrow at the bottom of the dialog box and select "COM Add-Ins" from the list, then click the GO button. What comes up is a list of COM-Add Ins that are loaded and running.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one feature of automatically pasting through load of excel sheets in MS Excel 2019, however this one is set only to [populate sheets in current workbook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3361-excel-copy-into-from-multiple-worksheets.html).

You should definitely check a `Home > Fill > Across Worksheets` setting and see if a special distribution applied here (and you have to go one by one, because this setting is workbook specific).

Apart from this, there is no such feature you mentioned. Having said this if above mentioned is not the case, I would blame one of these culprits:

- Advanced clipboard manager if present (please check and try to identify, it is not very probable but better always check)
- One of excel files might be a macro-enabled (.xlsm) and could control a clipboard content. In this case, please edit your question and elaborate more.
- Last and worst option is that a worm or malware could be screwing up with your data distribution. In this case I would check with some anti-malware tool like [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/for-home/products) for example.

Anyway, if you would be able to share problematic workbook, it could help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

There IS another way this can occur.

If more than one worksheet is selected when pasting (or performing pretty much ANY other action ON a worksheet), the paste occurs in the same place on all selected worksheets.

*(The use of such a thing is editing pages that have identical structure and formatting. One edit, in one place, takes effect across all of them preserving their "identical structure and formatting." It is also exceedingly faster than any other way (outside VBA of course) of doing such editing.)*

How to tell if this is your issue? Check via any method you have for whether more than one worksheet is selected. The usual way would be to see if more than one tab is selected (the tab row at the bottom). Other ways could include considering any macros you have that may be controlling or interjecting worksheet selection, or using VBA yourself to report what the current selection is. Bear in mind that checking the usual way needs to have no assumptions made to shorten the effort:  roll the tabs by from start to finish using the scroll control to see every tab and whether it is highlighted or not.

If you prefer a lazier way (or, I'm sure, what one might consider a "work smarter, not harder" way), make a definitive single tab selection, copy a row and paste it, then look at the other worksheets you are used to seeing the problem in. If the paste operation happened in them too, then the `Home|Fill|Across Worksheets` way it could happen would be a VERY likely possibility. But if macros are present, they will always be suspects until examined and proven not to be culprits.